# Add animation order to animate.css

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation, animate.css

I would like to add a delay between each animation when using `animate.css` so they will animate in order. For example, `northernlighting.no` (menu li items).

The problem is I have no idea how to animate each element instead of animating the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can do this.

Make sure you have a "hidden" class assigned to whatever you're animating.

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Your HTML would be like this

```
<ul>
    <li id="content1" class="hidden">
    <li id="content2" class="hidden">
    <li id="content3" class="hidden">
</ul>
```

jQuery would be like so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content1").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#content1").addClass("animated fadeIn");
    $("#content2").delay("slow").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#content2").addClass("animated fadeIn");
    $("#content3").delay("slow").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#content3").addClass("animated fadeIn");
});
```